# Dataset in Custom Code

Tags: reporting-services

How do I calculate the formula `Sum([PRODUCT_VAL] ) for Distinct( [ID])` in SSRS?

`[PRODUCT_VAL]` and `[ID]` are two columns in the dataset.

I think I need to iterate through rows of a DataSet in custom reports code, to find `Distinct [ID]` and make `SUM` for those values `[PRODUCT_VAL]`, but is it possible?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here. You can calculate both `=Sum(Fields!PRODUCT_VAL.Value)` and `=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value)` in your report. Can you add more detail to your question, such as some sample data and your desired results? The specific version of SSRS would also be useful.

Comment: 1. I want to calculate [PRODUCT_VAL] for distinct [ID].               2. SSRS 2008 R2                                                                   3. I already have a table that displays different columns of the dataset.                                                                      4. Sum([PRODUCT_VAL] ) For Distinct( [ID]) - is located at the bottom of the table

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do a sum where the `ID` is a certain value, similar to the `SUMIF` function in Excel? Two ways you can achieve this (let's say `1` is the value of `ID` that you want to select on):

**SSRS Expression**

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!ID.Value = 1, Fields!PRODUCT_VAL.Value, 0.00))
```

**SQL in your dataset**

```
SELECT ID, PRODUCT_VAL, CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN PRODUCT_VAL END AS ProductValForID1
FROM MyTable
```

and then sum on the `ProductValForID1` field.